# Frequent updates on cached data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I'm currently caching posts using laravel's built in caching with redis. however i'm running into a problem when caching posts. i basically have a column called score in the posts table that gets updated whenever user upvotes/downvotes and the problem is that if a user upvotes or downvotes a cached post the score column doesn't update until 10 minutes pass (that's how many minutes until the cache changes using laravel's built in Cache::remember function. What's the best way to solve this? Here is a code example of what i mean

```
public function home(Request $request)
    {
        //Get posts that have high scores and in the last 7 days..
//       $posts = Post::with('user')->orderBy('score','desc')->whereRaw('created_at >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY')->paginate(30);
       $page = $request->has('page') ? $request->query('page') : 1;
       //$posts = Post::with('user')->orderBy('score','desc')->paginate(50); 
      $posts = Cache::remember('posts' . $page, 10, function(){
      return Post::with('user')->orderBy('score','desc')->paginate(1);
});
       return view('posts.home', compact('posts','page'));
    }
```

Everything works perfectly and the posts are cached the problem appears when the user upvotes/downvotes. the score column doesn't update

Comment: Have the upvote/downvote endpoints invalidate the relevant cache item. You can even do this via events on the model so any time a model changes the relevant cache(s) are always cleared automatically.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - don't cache what's frequently updating (especially if you do sorting along with pagination). Re-query your database and **use indices** for performance.

However, if you still want to chase your approach...
`score` should be updated in the database, but you get socalled `stale` data from the cache. You may want to `Cache::forget('posts' . $page);` when you update the score (I recommend using events), so you're querying the most uptodate data, whenever the score was updated.